# css flex - maximise items size while keeping them filling different size container

Tags: javascript, css, flexbox

I'm trying to create a component that will show a flowing grid of same-sized items (number of whom can vary) in a different sized container. I'd like the items to be as large as possible (while keeping their ratio) and fill the container as much as possible while keeping nicely contained inside.

I've created a snippet with a hard coded scale values but my question is - can this (the scaling) be done automatically?
Or at least what approach can you suggest to make the calculation to do it?

So far the only thing I could think of is trying different scales and measuring the final area but it doesn't seem very elegant.

Thanks

```js
function set_state(cls, scl) {
  document.getElementById("cont").className = cls;

  [].slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("it"))
    .map((e) => {
      e.style.width = 50 * scl + 'px';
      e.style.height = 70 * scl + 'px';
    });

}
```

```css
#cont {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #00ff00;
}

.it {
  width: 50px;
  height: 70px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: #b33;
}

.shape1 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
}
.shape2 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 400px;
}
.shape3 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 500px;
}
.shape4 {
  width: 290px;
  height: 280px;
}
.shape5 {
  width: 210px;
  height: 380px;
}
```

```html
No Scale
<button onClick='set_state("shape1", 1)'>shape 1</button>
<button onClick='set_state("shape2", 1)'>shape 2</button>
<button onClick='set_state("shape3", 1)'>shape 3</button>
<button onClick='set_state("shape4", 1)'>shape 4</button>
<button onClick='set_state("shape5", 1)'>shape 5</button>

<br/><br/>
Scale
<button onClick='set_state("shape1", .8)'>shape 1</button>
<button onClick='set_state("shape2", .92)'>shape 2</button>
<button onClick='set_state("shape3", 1.45)'>shape 3</button>
<button onClick='set_state("shape4", 1)'>shape 4</button>
<button onClick='set_state("shape5", 1)'>shape 5</button>

<br/><br/><br/><br/>

<div id="cont" class="shape5">
  <div class="it">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="it">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="it">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="it">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="it">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="it">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="it">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="it">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="it">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="it">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a css demo with `flex : x x x;` and `max-width` and `min-width` + a wrapping container which can be resized like a textarea.

Similar to what you set via javascript.

Values to set is the `flex-basis` , `max/min-width` and the **vertical** `padding` of the pseudo element.

The ratio is set via the pseudo element.

```css
#cont {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 15px;
  justify-content:center;
}

.it {
  background: tomato;
  margin:1em;
  flex:1 0 15%;
  max-width:15%;
  min-width:100px;
}
.it:before {
  content:'';
  display:block;;
  padding-top:100%;
}
/* demo purpose */
.resize {
  resize: both;
  border: solid;
  overflow: scroll;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="resize">
<h1> to run in full page mode to test behavior</h1>
  <div id="cont">
    <div class="it">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="it">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="it">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="it">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="it">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="it">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="it">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="it">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="it">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="it">&nbsp;</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

... if i understood the question :)

Comment: Sorry for a slow reply... Unfortunately, it's not what I was trying to achieve. My goal is to create a responsive layout that will fill any available space while making the inner items as large as possible... Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @xims them flex:1; and a min-width to child should do and allow wrapping, but ratio will not be kept. every rows might have a different height and last row will extand the few last item to fill it entirely. I think i partially misunderstood the question where ratio seems in the way. :) http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GWxooj

Comment: Here is my codepen, it's easier to see than the one here - http://codepen.io/xim/pen/VpXMGX It's crucial the items are kept in the same ratio. And the problem is that we don't know how many items in a row will give a maximum coverage... Maybe it's not possible, just wanted to confirm it. Thank you!

Comment: @xims i think my answer was closer to your needs, you need to play around with the min/max/width and use a pseudo to expand the box to your ratio needed. a variant from answer : http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/zZWpKe

Comment: I appreciate your continuous help and you're using some cool commands but it's not doing the main thing I need - scaling the items to max to fill as much space as possible - https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6ehLUydBUm6WnlMNHNMdUVKeEE/view?usp=drivesdk - here the items can be 3 times bigger, and here https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6ehLUydBUm6eVV1RjlfY0NtUDA/view?usp=drivesdk they don't even fit into the area

Comment: @xims would min/max width be in the way ? http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/wJmpXp (i hardly understand the goal, cause scaling down if it holds content, it would be unreadable at one point :) ...

Comment: Please try to understand the goal because your code is great but it's not doing anything I'm after. Don't worry about readability, it's not about that. I have rectangular items with a specific width/height ratio. I have a container that can be any shape (basically anything from portrait phone to 4k landscape desktop). I'd like the items to be as big as possible to occupy as much of the container space without scroll and without having too much empty space.

Comment: If you need an example to better understand the context - imagine a page of the photo album with, say, 12 thumbnails on a page. The page can be anything depends on the device. But thumbs come in a specific shape and total number on the page is constant. So here I'd like to show the thumbs as large as possible to fill the space and without scroll. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: @xims okay , something like this http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/vxRwBm . flex is not needed for inline-block elements **but javascript will be required**  to retrieve ratio img and set a width/max-width value. Demo is using average vh and vw value.

Comment: @xims img can be used to set the ration if you only set style on width **or** height, width or height will adjust itself. inline-block wrapper (or flex child) can  expand/shrink to the img size.